# Changing the format of a spreadsheet cell via OnlyOffice API

Tags: spreadsheet, onlyoffice

I use OnlyOffice conversion service to obtain a `xlsx` spreadsheet from a `csv` file.

The original `csv` contains some fields that are logically dates, but of course in the converted `xlsx` every cell has the *General* format.

Is it possible to change the format of a cell/column via API to assign the *Date* format?

I'm using OnlyOffice 5.2.7